# Typescript interfaces behaving differently when used as part of constructor invocation vs regular function?

Tags: typescript

Why does the 1st example compile but the 2nd one generates "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target?"

```
interface Foo {
    s: string;
}

// example 1:
function abc(p: Foo[]) {    
}

// ok
abc([{s: ''}]);


// example 2:
class Blah {
    constructor(p: {stuff: Foo[]}) {
    }
}

// not ok: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
var obj = new Blah({stuff: [{s: ''}]});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the compiler. It's been fixed; the next release that will have the fix is 0.9.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I would add is that if you create an interface for `stuff` it will work:

```
interface Foo {
    s: string;
}

interface Stuff {
    stuff: Foo[];
}

// example 1:
function abc(p: Foo[]) {    
}

// ok
abc([{s: ''}]);


// example 2:
class Blah {
    constructor(p: Stuff) {
    }
}

var obj = new Blah({stuff: [{s: ''}]});
```

[See it in the TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%3a%20string;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Stuff%20%7B%0D%0A%09stuff%3a%20Foo%5B%5D;%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A//%20example%201%3a%0D%0Afunction%20abc%28p%3a%20Foo%5B%5D%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A//%20ok%0D%0Aabc%28%5B%7Bs%3a%20%27%27%7D%5D%29;%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A//%20example%202%3a%0D%0Aclass%20Blah%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28p%3a%20Stuff%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20obj%20=%20new%20Blah%28%7Bstuff%3a%20%5B%7Bs%3a%20%27%27%7D%5D%7D%29;).